# Kubuntu 22.04 War Thunder Crashes After Startup

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, games, steam, crash

Sorry for posting this here but I couldn't get much help in the War Thunder forums.

After launching the game and loading into the hangar (rendered main menu) it stays fine for a while but crashes immediately when I interact with anything.

I remember playing War Thunder fine on Windows and on Ubuntu MATE on this system perfectly fine before.

Crash Report:

[image: Crash Report]

System Info:

[image: System Info]